# i want to get distinct row count from two tables not having foreign key. Mysql version 5.5

Tags: mysql

I have a `column1` and `column2` with same field; I want to get `distinct` `row count` from two tables.

I tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT test_setting.imei)
FROM test_setting, wcdma_tests
WHERE wcdma_tests.imei = test_setting.imei;
```

Comment: HI there! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Everyone here will do their best to help you solve any problems you may be having. Right now your question is a little bit hard to parse. You might want to take a look at How To Ask A Question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT i.imei)
FROM test_setting i join wcdma_tests a on i.imei = a.imei
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks it works.
But i want distinct rows from test_setting even if the records are absent in wcdma_tests.
can I do like this ??

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT i.imei)
      FROM test_setting i LEFT JOIN wcdma_tests a on i.imei = a.imei;